# How to open a folder on notepad++ using windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, notepad++

I wonder if there is a way to open a folder in notepad++ from command line on windows..I can open a single file, but i want to know how to open folders as workspace (not from notepad++ dashboard) but from command line.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Workaround: open a file that does *not* exist, e.g. *tmp.txt*, and Notepad++ asks if you want to create it. At that point, you're working in the correct folder, but with an extra empty file. Or, open *desktop.ini* in that folder, which windows creates unbidden.

Comment: Thanks, That will open a single file without the folder tree on dashboard left side. We need to open folder as workspace on the left too.

Answer (score 2):

There is apparently no options to open as workspace with command-line described in the [documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Command_Line_Switches).

But you can open all files in a folder by typing

`start notepad++.exe web`

Where **web** is a folder on my desktop

Or if you are already in the web folder

`start notepad++.exe .`

Comment: well, this is not always helpful, especially if you the root folder has a large subdirectory like "node_modules" or any other third-party modules with thousands of files.

Comment: @shireefkhatab Yes you're right .. ;)